# Rectangle Fill Colour in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I created a rectangle using Kinetic.Line. I want to fill by colour.but it is not working.Can anyone help?

```
var square1 = new Kinetic.Line({
    x:10,
    y: stage.getHeight()*0.5,
    points: [0,0,0,30,30,30,30,0,0,0],
    id:"object3",       
    fill:'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    draggable:true,
    closed: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
        return {
          x: pos.x,
          y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
        }
    }   
 });
```

Comment: works for me. http://jsbin.com/vanojo/1/edit